# Dspace import failed

Tags: collections, repository, digital, dspace

I just installed Dspace 5.4 and I am trying to move a collection from greenstone to Dspace.

I successfully exported the collection from greenstone but when I try to load it into Dspace via batch import (zip) I get the following error:

```
Notice

Import failed

/dspace/imports/New Folder.zip/New Folder/exported_DSpace/dublin_core.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Can anyone tell me what have I missed?

Answer (score 5):

We do not have a great deal of information to go on from your question, such as how you did the export from greenstone. From what I can tell, it seems possible that you did not export the data in the correct format for dspace.

The structure should be this [simple archive format](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC18/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format)

```
archive_directory/
  item_000/
    dublin_core.xml         -- qualified Dublin Core metadata for metadata fields belonging to the dc schema
    metadata_[prefix].xml   -- metadata in another schema, the prefix is the name of the schema as registered with the metadata registry
    contents                -- text file containing one line per filename
    file_1.doc              -- files to be added as bitstreams to the item
    file_2.pdf
  item_001/
    dublin_core.xml
    contents
    file_1.png
    ...
```

To export a collection from greenstone so it is suitable for dspace you can follow these steps it seems. [Here is some information that might help](http://wiki.greenstone.org/gsdoc/tutorial/gs2-current/en/greenstone_to_dspace.htm)
It seems possible that you have exported the data from greenstone but not in the correct format for DSpace.

For some more information on how the structure should look like when importing data into DSpace, you can take a look at [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC18/Importing+and+Exporting+Items+via+Simple+Archive+Format)

Comment: Hi Dylan, I used the export tool in Greenstone and selected the dspace format. The folder structure is as follows: archive_directory/ item1_directory/ docmets.xml, doctxt.xml, file1.pdf. i.e 2 xml files and the item.

Comment: @NasYakubu That format does indeed miss the dublin_core.xml file. You could, perhaps, write a script to do the export from greenstone. You could generate the required files/file-structure yourself. In the link I have provided there is an example of how this should look like. Did you generate the archive based on the link?